# Get rid of a row identifier in R

Tags: r, matrix

My program correctly outputs the results of two `data.frame`s

```
Browse[2]> Mismatch
    Num.Residue PDB.Residue Canonical.Residue
1          61           H                 Q
```

and

```
Browse[2]> PDBXPoly$Diffs.Matrix
   PDB.Residue Canonical.Residue Position
19           H                 Q       61
```

My question is, how to get rid of the "1" and the "19"? They are artificats from the larger `data.frame` that I pulled the output from.

Answer (score 3):

Are those matrices or data frames? They look like data frames.

The 1 and the 19 are row names. If those are matrices, you can get rid of the row names with

```
row.names(Mismatch) = NULL
```

If those are data frames, you can't "remove" the row.names, but the line above will turn them into sequential rownames (if you don't want to retain them from the larger data frame).

ETA: You can print the data frame without row names like this:

```
print(Matrix, row.names=FALSE)
print(PDBXPoly$Diffs.Matrix, row.names=FALSE)
```